# Why does updating the metadata of my pdf in iTextSharp always append the 'subject' to the end of the 'keywords'?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm doing a bulk update of the meta data in a bunch of PDF files and for some reason the subject is always being appended to the end of the keywords metadata. Even if I remove the 'Keywords' update it is still being updated when I update the data.

Is this expected? Has anyone else seen this before?

```
private void ProcessWithITextSharp(string sourceFile, string destFile) {

iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader( sourceFile );
FileStream fs = new FileStream( destFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None );
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper( reader, fs );

Dictionary<string, string> info = reader.Info;

// title
UpdateValueInInfoDictionary( info, "Title", "My Ridiculous Title" );
UpdateValueInInfoDictionary( info, "Subject", "A Ridiculous Story" );
UpdateValueInInfoDictionary( info, "Author", "Mr. Ridiculous " );
UpdateValueInInfoDictionary( info, "Keywords", "A ridiculous story with a ridiculous title." );

stamper.MoreInfo = info;
stamper.Close();
fs.Close();
```

}

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code for `UpdateValueInInfoDictionary()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar today and had the same problem.  (Drove me nuts)  If you save the file and reopen it, you'll notice the MetaData property of the PdfReader still has many of the original values before saving.  I solved the problem by stuffing in these three lines after stamper.MoreInfo = info;

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
XmpWriter xw = new XmpWriter(ms,info);
stamper.XmpMetadata = ms.GetBuffer();
```

and at the top:

```
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp;
```

Hope this helps the next person who finds this :)